# .env variables with Vite not changing in the browser

Tags: reactjs, firefox, chromium, vite

I have a React app that I have migrated to Vite from CRA for bundling/serving. Since I am re-using the API wrapper that communicates with the backend in other projects, I made it a library distributed via npm. The backend URL should be configurable from the frontend using the library, so with CRA I defined it from a .env file and accessing them from within the library using `process.env.REACT_APP*`. Now with Vite, I am trying to achieve the same thing, so in my library (that bundles with rollup) I am letting the library consumer set the backend URL by reading `import.meta.env.VITE_`, which in the consuming React app is stored in a .env file.

In principle, this is working, but  sometimes it seems that env variables are cached somewhere, because my changes to them in the .env file are not always reflected in the version served by `npm start`, and inconsistently so between browsers: for some hours Firefox was using a stale env value, then it suddenly worked, and now Chromium is behaving equally weird, although Firefox is working now. Neither re-starting the dev server nor my PC (!) seems to be working. I am completely lost as to why this is happening and why it is arbitrarily happening in different browsers at different times across re-boots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***** UPDATE #2 *****

So apparently, it seems like process.env had the variables after the build so I just ended up checking if it's PROD to use the `process.env.VARIABLE_NAME`, and if it's not PROD I use `window.process.env.VARIABLE_NAME`

---

***** UPDATE #1 *****

Seems like it's working only when running localhost. Still checking why it won't work after the build. Will update you when I manage to solve it.

---

For anyone who still faces this issue, I managed to solve it by installing `vite-plugin.environment` and importing it inside `vite.config`

```js
import EnvironmentPlugin from 'vite-plugin-environment';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), EnvironmentPlugin('all', { prefix: 'VITE_' })],

  // ... rest of your configuration
})
```

Then within the consumed package built using rollup, I changed `process.env.VARIABLE_NAME` to `window.process.env.VARIABLE_NAME`.

It seems like it's working thanks to `EnvironmentPlugin`, which also injects the `process.env` inside `window`.

Answer (score 2):

In my case this is what was happening with react vite dev server.

I updated the env values and restarted the dev server but still the browser is seeing old value even in incognito or even clearing browser cache.

The way I resolved this is by manually clearing the env at system level.

1. Check from your terminal to see the values of the envs using `printenv` command. You should see all system env including `VITE_`
2. Delete all variable with `VITE_` prefix using this command or any other method `for var in ${(k)parameters}; do [[ $var == VITE_* ]] && unset $var; done`
   3.Restart vite dev server for your app

In a React app created with Vite, environment variables are typically loaded during the build process, and their values are embedded directly into the compiled JavaScript code. They are not stored as cache files that you can manually delete. So evene deleting node modules will not work as well

Comment: UPDATE: Sometimes you have to run the command more than once in order to clear  all the cached env

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I have found a way to seemingly solve this: nuking `/node_modules` and reinstalling the project seems to get rid of this.

Comment: This deosn't work

Comment: Same, does not work